# Tried everything but still couldn't simulate mouse click on element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, mouseclick-event

I am trying to simulate a mouse click on the Download button of [canva.com](https://www.canva.com) designs. I managed to do it with other buttons, but not for the "Download" button (nor for any of the buttons in the top menu).

Here are the ways I've tried:

```
$x.click();

$x.trigger('click');

$x.trigger('mousedown');

$x[0].click();

document.querySelector('...').click();

$x[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));

var evt = new CustomEvent("MouseEvents");
$x[0].dispatchEvent(evt);

var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.querySelector("...").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Any ideas?

PS 1: CSS selector of the button: `document.querySelector(".KnkXXg._4dXjgA.gLTEuQ.XvGYmg._2ELgpQ._4dXjgA.gLTEuQ.XvGYmg.spExZw.AvEAGQ.vM2UTA.iSx4Ig.DM1_6g")`

PS 2: to test it, go to [canva.com](https://www.canva.com), create a new design and add some text (just to enable the download button).

PS 3: I'm open to solutions that involves Chrome extension API too.

Thank you.

Comment: What's `$x` in your case?  Looks like you're using the console: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#xpath

Comment: It's not shown on a click event, it's on mousedown - you can confirm by pressing and holding mouse button down - click event occurs when you stop holding the mouse down

Comment: @freedomn-m $x is just a shortcut (I didn't want to write all the button selector because it's too long), but it should be replaced with the selector ".KnkXXg._4dXjgA.gLTEuQ.XvGYmg._2ELgpQ._4dXjgA.gLTEuQ.XvGYmg.spExZw.AvEAGQ.vM2UTA.iSx4Ig.DM1_6g"

Comment: @freedomn-m You're right! it's a mousedown event! I just tested it with document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); and set "mousedown" as the event in evt.initMouseEvent and it did work though! Thank you so much! , you saved my day :)